# Path to access a java web service?

Tags: web-services

I created a simple java class and created a web service based on that class using a bottom up approach. I am able to create the service in eclipse but for checking the WSDL file through browser (to confirm the web service is deployed successfully) i am not sure what URL (basically the path) should i use. I tried using URL

```
http://localhost:8080/POSStore/ConsultServices?WSDL
```

but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

[image: Eclipse project screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Instead i need to use below URL. Though not sure why services was included in the path.

```
http://localhost:8080/POSStore/services/ConsultServices?WSDL
```